# android back navigation on child method?

Tags: android

im creating redirect to some view on object method. this method doesn't use the parent view.

it works but when i click back navigation it doesn't showing the previous page (previous page is object oncreate() method itself), it return to the top parent activity. here is my code :

Object method on create :

```
public class FormDatabase extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.form_database);
```

method member of object method :

```
 public void showArrayResult(View view)
    {
        setContentView(R.layout.profile_listview);
```

how can when i click back navigation i would return to previous object onCreate() method NOT the parent method (MAIN_ACTIVITY).

Hope my description is clear enough. Thanks.

Comment: You have all of the activities in your manifest file right? And the are all marked so you have history to them righr

Comment: sorry i dont understand... what u mean sir

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To switch between different views in the same activity, and still maintain the ability to use the back stack (back button), you should probably use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments.html).

If the two views are completely independent then you should consider moving it into its own separate Activity.

Comment: is there any chance i can return to the active activity (Oncreate method of current object) ?

Comment: You might want to read up on some of the basics of android, like the lifecycle of activities and fragments. The activity should only need to go through the oncreate when it is created. See https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html for some more details

Answer (score 1):

You can override the onBackPressed() callback method to interrupt killing the activity and instead SetContentView as you did in onCreate()

EDIT

But Nic is right about moving to a fragment or another activity.

A component such as an activity should manage one task. Otherwise it is considered as bad practice.

Comment: so i would create method--> onBackPressed on the method (showArrayResult) so it would make back navigation return to FormDatabase (active activity) ?

Comment: The callback method belongs to the activity and not to custom methods like showArrayResult. It alter app behaviors when the user clicks the back button from a specific activity

Comment: im already find reference about overiding the onBackPressed. unfortunately it's not what i try to accomplish. thanks